# How to terminate Voximplant session correctly?

Tags: voximplant

How do I terminate a Voximplant session after a call? Do I do this way:
outgoing.addEventListener(CallEvents.Disconnected, VoxEngine.terminate);
Or this way: VoxEngine.terminate.bind(VoxEngine)?

Answer (score 0):

The first variant is correct. Alternatively, the session automatically terminates a minute after the call ends.